# Why doesn't this class take the parents' methods

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

For some reason, the `CaeserText` class does not inherit the `ShiftText` class methods.

`ShiftText.h`:

```cpp
class ShiftText : public PlainText
{
protected:
    int key;

public:
    ShiftText(string text, int key);
    ~ShiftText();

    static string encrypt(string text, int key);
    static string decrypt(string text, int key);
    
    string encrypt();
    string decrypt();
};
```

`CaesarText.h`:

```cpp
class CaesarText : public ShiftText
{
public:
    CaesarText(string text);
    ~CaesarText();

    // hiding the previous methods of the ShiftText class
    static string encrypt(string text);
    static string decrypt(string text);
};
```

The function that's giving me the error:

```cpp
PlainText Bob(CaesarText msg)
{
    cout << endl << "Bob:" << endl;
    cout << "The received message: " << msg.getText() << endl;
    cout << "The decrypted message is: " << msg.decrypt() << endl;
    return PlainText("Many Thanks Alice!");
}
```

Some background:

The `ShiftText` function takes a key and a string and it moves the string based on the key, for example:

If the `key` is 3 then `a` will turn into `d`, etc.

The `CaesarText` class should do the same, but instead of moving by a chosen key, the `key` is ALWAYS 3.

The error:

> 'CaesarText::decrypt': function does not take 0 arguments

Shouldn't the `CaesarText::decrypt` method inherit from its parent?

If it would have, then this error wouldn't have existed.

Comment: Hiding is based *only* on name. Not signature, or static versus non-static.

Comment: It tries to call the static function defined in the derived class, not the non-static method of the parent. Use different names for static and non-static methods in your classes to avoid name collisions and, then, actually call the non-static method which seems to be your intent.

Comment: Learn a bit more about virtual functions and overriding them. E.g. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/virtual-functions/ (and its [previous lesson](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/pointers-and-references-to-the-base-class-of-derived-objects/) too). And replace new with `std::make_unique` and the raw pointers with `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Simple solution: In the `CaesarText` class add `using ShiftText::decrypt;`

Comment: `CaesarText` inheriting `PlainText` is probably a bad idea. Public inheritance models the "is-a" relationship. Your classes do not model texts anyway. They should probably be called "...EncryptionMethod" rather than "...Text"